# Primefaces validate form using Ajax

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to validate a form on with Ajax set to true, 
here is my JSF code for the button:

```
<p:commandButton value="doit" action="#{form.checkForm}" ajax="true" validateClient="true" update="test0 test1 test2 test3 test4"/>
```

and in the `web.xml` i've added:

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.CLIENT_SIDE_VALIDATION</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

now the input that i want to validate are not in the update attribut,
when i set the `ajax="false"` the validating works fine, and i get the messages, but when i set it to true, i dont get anything.

so how can i get it to validate the form with ajax set to true?

Comment: What's the purpose of the client side validation here? Don't confuse client side validation with the ajax one (which is done in the server).

Comment: To calculate the test0 .. test4 fields, some other inputs needs to be validated(example correct date, positive numbers) then if the inputs are correct, execute the "checkForm" method. Or am i doing it in the wrong way? cuz with ajax set to false it works great, but the page has to reload and its a bit slow.

Comment: If ajax set to false, the current form where the component lives is sent. In your case the form which contains the `p:commandButton`. If ajax used, you can choose what you want to process. [It seems](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=14647) `p:commandButton` processes all the components in the view, that's why it might be failing. The solution might be to attach a `process="@form"` to your button.

Comment: ok this kinda work, work it does not show the "messages".